# ModuleNotFoundError: "No module named 'pymongo'

Tags: python

So I have a folder structured as follows:

```
Project
|
+-- __init__.py
|     
+-- db 
|   +-- db_helper.py
|   +-- test.py
|   +-- __init__.py //indicating its a package
|
```

Within my **db_helper.py** file, I have an import:

```
import pymongo
```

This works when applied to my **test.py** file like so:

```
from db_helper import db_helper
```

But when I try to import **db_helper** to my **__init__.py** like so:

```
from .db import db_helper
```

I'm getting this error:

```
File "/Project__init__.py, line 14, in <module>"
from .db import db_helper
File "/Project/db/db_helper.py, line 1, in <module>"
import pymongo
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'pymongo'
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks a lot :)

Edit: Add more context for root problem

Comment: have you installed pymongo? If yes, how?

Comment: works on my computer, using python 3.6, with from db import db_helper instead of .db . Which version of python are you using ?

Comment: @FlorianH yes pymongo is installed, it is working within the test.py script.

Answer (score 0):

> Please do one thing that keep the **init**.py inside the db folder.

```
Keep the blank __init__.py  file inside the db folder.
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that in the directory chart, there is an __Init__.py inside the db folder, I will edit the original post to show this.